# leaflet dragging marker with circle

Tags: javascript, event-handling, leaflet

I want to drag my marker and then the circle to appear where i left the marker. But i cant get it done. I cant understand why... the previous circle disappears but the new one isnt appearing.
here is my code :

```
...
var marker;
var circle;
var all;
mymap.on('click', function (e) {
  if (all) {
    mymap.removeLayer(all);
  }
  marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng,{draggable:true});
  circle  = new L.circle(e.latlng, {radius: 600});
   marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
   if (circle) {
    mymap.removeLayer(circle);
   }
   var newPos = e.target.getLatLng();
   circle  = new L.circle(newPos, {radius: 600});
    });

   all = L.layerGroup([marker, circle]);
   mymap.addLayer(all);
});
...
```

Comment: Can you add a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? It will be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it the problem was that the layer of the circle wasn't combined again with the marker after the drag event so it wasn't showing on the map.So what i had to do it to include inside the 'dragend' function again the code

```
all = L.layerGroup([marker, circle]);
   mymap.addLayer(all);
```

to combine the new circle again with the marker.Now its working perfect .Sorry for posting without working hard on it.

so the finished code would look like this :

...

```
 marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
   if (circle) {
    mymap.removeLayer(circle);
   }
   var newPos = e.target.getLatLng();
   circle  = new L.circle(newPos, {radius: 600});
       all = L.layerGroup([marker, circle]);
       mymap.addLayer(all);
    });

   all = L.layerGroup([marker, circle]);
   mymap.addLayer(all);
});
```

...